# How to know when Firebase DataSnapshot has been persisted server side

Tags: android, swift, firebase, mobile, persistence

I'm building a chat using Firebase, using offline feature (`keepSynced(true)`)

It works very well except that I cant find a way to know if the DataSnapshot message has indeed been saved server side, as if I query for the message Firebase will tell me that it exists (it does locally!).

I found about transactions but it does not save offline.

I also found about checking the connection status of Firebase, but it is a global status, and does not reflect one by one snapshot status.

The only solution that I found is adding a property "persisted" on my message objected, this property being set by a server side function, but that seems overkill for this purpose. I'm pretty sure Firebase does know locally which values are not persisted yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, when you perform any operation that writes, you will either get a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) object in return, or you may specify a [CompletionListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener.html) as an argument.  Either of these will indicate when the data is received by the server.  If you don't use these, you have no other indication.

Using a Cloud Function to tag the location upon write is certainly another way to do it, if you can't hold on to the Task or CompletionListener.

Comment: Good catch ! there is a callback in iOS too. But this wont persist if for example I leave the chat screen and come back to it, I have no idea wether or not the message has been sent (I dont think I can hold the task between app restart etc). I'm gonna stick with the cloud function then ! thanks for your help